# Play audio in background by use BackgroundCapableMedia

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In the windows8 Developer preview we can use this code to play audio in background:

```
mediaElement.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.Media;
```

In the windows8 Customer perview, It seems that we should use AudioCategory.BackgroundCapableMedia instead of AudioCategory.Media

```
mediaElement.AudioCategory=AudioCategory.BackgroundCapableMedia;
```

and I also Declare a background task in appxmanifest

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="TestApp.App">
      <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="audio" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

but it didn't work for me and the MediaElement will throw an "MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED“ exception in MediaFailed EventHandler
How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set up these event handlers:

`using Windows.Media;`

```
MediaControl.PlayPressed += MediaControl_PlayPressed;
MediaControl.PausePressed += MediaControl_PausePressed;
MediaControl.PlayPauseTogglePressed += MediaControl_PlayPauseTogglePressed;
MediaControl.StopPressed += MediaControl_StopPressed;
```

-

```
void MediaControl_StopPressed(object sender, object e)
{
    myMediaPlayer.Stop();
}

void MediaControl_PlayPauseTogglePressed(object sender, object e)
{
}

void MediaControl_PausePressed(object sender, object e)
{
    myMediaPlayer.Pause();
}

void MediaControl_PlayPressed(object sender, object e)
{
    myMediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

I think that should have it working.

Comment: For Windows 8.1+, use `SystemMediaTransportControls`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249916/how-to-switch-from-mediaelement-to-backgroundmediaplayer-on-application-lose-foc/28250692#28250692).