# Play audio in Windows 8 apps without Media element?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I want to play audio in a Windows 8 app without using the Media element. Media Element needs to be attached to the Visual Tree of each page. Since all pages in my app use background audio, I have to attach the MediaElement in the App frame. The whole thing kind of sucks. I will appreciate if someone can provide me pointers to play audio in Windows 8 app without this Media element non-sense.

Comment: +1 thank you for this question because I would do it sooner or later. I thought of using DirectX but I have no experience with it so I don't know if it is easily doable.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564544/play-audio-in-background-by-use-backgroundcapablemedia

Comment: The question does not help me. The MediaElement should still be added to the XAML to play audio. I am trying to play audio without any changes to the XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the property on your MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMedia" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia />
```

The content of this MediaElement will then play even on other pages and when your app is suspended. You also need to set a capability **Background Tasks -> Audio** in the app manifest that your app supports background audio.

Nice tutorial how to use this feature is here:
[Background Audio c# Metro](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-c-Metro-d2fc7719)
or here:
[Play audio in background by use BackgroundCapableMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564544/play-audio-in-background-by-use-backgroundcapablemedia)

Comment: MediaElement is a pain. You have to add it to the XAML. Without adding it in the XAML you cannot play audio. I need it for each and every page.